# Using apt install in custom cloud native buildpack

Tags: buildpack

I am trying to create a custom buildpack using this [tutorial](https://buildpacks.io/docs/buildpack-author-guide/create-buildpack/). I want to use this buildpack for one of the spring boot apps along with other available buildpacks. The buildpack installs tesseract using apt. But I am getting the below exception:

[Error when installing tesseract in buildpacks base image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MMQob.png)

My understanding is this builder image with `cnb` as the user who doesn't have these permissions. Adding `sudo` gives `command not found`.

One way to solve this is to create a Dockerfile with this as the base and do anything needed there as root user and use the resulting image as the builder base image. `pack build` doesn't have an option to pass the user like `docker container run`. But this may not be as flexible as buildpacks since the latter can be selected or eliminated using some condition in the detect phase, and so I can specify all the buildpacks in the spring-boot-maven-plugin configuration. Since the whole objective of CNB is to avoid/replace the Dockerfiles, is there any option I am missing here, or is this the only way?

PS: I tried running the base builder as root and achieved what I needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a community supported [apt-buildpack](https://github.com/fagiani/apt-buildpack) that may help. I believe you would create a `Aptfile` in your repo with contents like:

```
tesseract
```

Depending on how you're running CNBs, you could add this to your build with a command like:

```
$ pack build -b fagiani/apt@0.1.0
```

For more info see the registry entry for [fagiani/apt](https://registry.buildpacks.io/buildpacks/fagiani/apt)

Comment: This worked but I think it's because the builder image is `heroku/buildpacks:18`. I will check other things and see if I can use this as the builder for all services. I also raised an issue if the current builder I am using `paketo-buildpacks/builder:base` by default. I am accepting your answer. Thanks!!